# Extension Library osgi not loading properly

Tags: http, lotus-domino, osgi-bundle

On one of my clients sites they deleted the updatesite.nsf and created a new one (with the same name) installed the latest Extension Library into the updatesite.nsf and signed the content by a person with All Admin Rights.

Did:
tell HTTP quit
load http

When it loaded the HTTP the console  message is:

HTTP JVM: NotesException: Invalid replica id (updatesite.nsf)

Shut the server down and restarted it with the same error when it came to load the HTTP. I had something like this happen on a new server I set up but the server was not set to have the admin rights. I don't know if this was happening with the previous updatesite.nsf before they deleted it.

Pretty much tried everything I can think of. Any ideas

Comment: Have you tried setting the replica id of the new updatesite.nsf to match the old updatesite.nsf's replica id?  There are a variety of tools that can do this.

Comment: Don't know the I'd of the old one as it was deleted.

Comment: There are no backups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much frustration I finally got them up and running and here is what we needed to do:

1. remove the reference in the Notes.ini to OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES in the server configuration document clear both the value and the parameter.
2. deleted the updatesite.nsf on the server (actually just moved it outside of the Data folder.
3. I tried just console restart of the server but did not work. Finally went to the Windows Services and actually stopped the service.
4. Started the service again. However, on the server start up there was the error message that there was an invalid repid for the update site.
5. from the console tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib and got a clean list of the default installed like this:

   tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  Framework is launched.
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  id        State       Bundle
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  91        <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  92        <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  93        <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  94        <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  95        <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
   07/08/2015 10:27:54 AM  96        <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
6. stopped the Domino Service and started it again got a clean start with no reference to the updatesite.nsf
7. created a new updatesite1.nsf and imported the latest extension library and signed the content.
8. added the OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES pointing to updatesite1.nsf
9. Stopped the domino service then restarted it.
10. startup loaded the correct OSGI without error and lists the correct extension library components.

I had tried this using tell HTTP quit and load HTTP but this did not work, only when I did a complete shutdown of the server did the changes really take place.
Rule number one be very careful if you need to delete an updatesite!