# Can not open XSP Properties in designer

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

at a clients site they had problems when they deleted an updatesite and created a new one. I was able to get that resolved and it now loads the correct updatesite.nsf 
[Extension Library osgi not loading properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843038/extension-library-osgi-not-loading-properly)

now they can not edit the XSP Properties in the designer client. An error message flashes on the screen but it is to fast to be able to read and just opens a blank screen. Also, will not open an existing Custom Control.
I had them do an install of the Notes/Designer/Admim over their existing install to no avail. The issue seems to be global because the designer client is installed on two different clients and they both respond the same.
Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Check Help > Support > View Log / View Trace. It's probably logging more information there.

Is this all xsp.properties files or just one? Also same for Custom Controls. A Custom Control comprised the .xsp file and a .xsp-config file that holds the custom properties, whether it appears in the palette etc. I broke a custom control by deleting that one. You can still get the to XML by right-clicking the custom control and choosing Open With > XML Editor. That will allow you to recreate it. You can use the same technique but open with text editor for xsp.properties. I've not heard of a problem with that, but if it's just one, try deleting and re-creating as a file called xsp.properties may allow it to work again.

Opening editors is standard Eclipse functionality and Eclipse isn't installed over the top of an existing installation, it's fresh, pointing to the same workspace. If it's for all applications, even a new one created from e.g. TeamRoom template, you may need to uninstall / re-install. Alternatively, deleting the workspace folder may clear it up.

Comment: What are the consequences of deleting the workspace folder for an application database? Are they recreated when the database is opened?

Comment: Deleting the workspace folder won't affect an application. You'll lose working sets and Eclipse-based preferences (basic settings pre-dating Notes 8.5 are stored in notes.ini, I believe). You can back up Eclipse preferences from any non-Domino perspective, I've blogged a bit about how to do that.